# Visual studio code and python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write a script and I put this down
`if _name_== '_main_':`

Now visual studio code isn't understanding `_name_` but I am following a video so I am pretty confused

It gave me an error code that said it was undefined

Comment: Both of those things are supposed to have two underscores on each end, not one...

Comment: why don't you check a website, maybe the official python website, so a web search, even if you type it wrong it will give you useful hits

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with VSC. When you run the code, Python will raise an error. VSC is just warning you ahead of time.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title, how to include all the necessary info, and to start with your own research.

Answer (score 0):

it should be two underscores instead of one.

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("hello")
```

More information about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Questions that can be resolved by fixing a typo usually get closed and/or deleted pretty quickly as they are [off-topic](/help/on-topic), so it's not recommended to add an answer.